# Has this "backwards" perspective on toposes been studied?

Tags: ct.category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topology, categorification, sites

Topos theory can be seen as a categorification of topology via the following analogies.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{locales}&\text{Grothendieck toposes}\\\hline
\text{open sets}&\text{sheaves}\\\hline
\text{continuous maps}&\text{geometric morphisms}\\\hline
\text{bases}&\text{sites}\\\hline
\text{topological spaces}&\text{ionads}\\\hline
\end{array}

But when I was first learning about topos theory I was temporarily confused by the following two results.

> **Proposition 1**
>
> For a set $S$ there's a correspondence between topologies on $S$ and finite limit preserving (necessarily idempotent) monads on $\mathbf{2}^S$. A topology corresponds to its closure operation.

> **Proposition 2**
>
> For a category $C$ there's a correspondence between Grothendieck topologies on $C$ and finite limit preserving idempotent monads on $\mathbf{Set}^{C^\mathrm{op}}$. A Grothendieck topology corresponds to its sheafification operation.

The similarity between these propositions suggests that we can also view topos theory as a categorification of topology in such a way that sheaves are the categorification of closed sets rather than open ones. From this strange perspective the analogies would be the following.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\text{topologies}&\text{Grothendieck topologies}\\\hline
\text{topological spaces}&\text{sites}\\\hline
\text{closed sets}&\text{sheaves}\\\hline
\text{continuous maps}&\text{morphisms of sites}\\\hline
\end{array}

---

Has this point of view been studied anywhere? Does it have any use?

Comment: This is really self promotion, but your question is related to my talk at CT: http://www.math.muni.cz/~diliberti/Talk/Scott.pdf

Comment: Isn't the closure operator of a topology a finite *colimit* preserving monad on a powerset?  Two disjoint sets can have closure points in common, so closure doesn't preserve intersections.

Comment: @MikeShulman I think that's the answer! How embarrassing.

Comment: @MikeShulman Add that as an answer?

Comment: @IvanDiLiberti Your link is broken :(

Comment: I am sorry! This is a working link! https://diliberti.github.io/Talk/Scott.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the closure operator of a topology is a finite *colimit* preserving monad on a powerset.

Comment: Did you really have to start it that way?

Comment: @DavidRoberts what?

Comment: Reads to me like a "well, actually...". No biggie, but the answer doesn't need it.

Comment: @DavidRoberts In my idiolect, the word "actually" is used when pointing out that the facts of a situation are different from what has previously been stated or assumed.  I think it is appropriate and useful here because the "answer" is not really answering the question asked, but instead pointing out that it is based on an incorrect premise, and the reader's attention should be drawn to that fact.